# SQL Server Dynamic Query Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

Need your help to figure out what is my mistakes using dynamic SQL Query.
Below is my sample query, but I cannot detect where are my mistakes.

```
DECLARE @p_orgcompreq NVARCHAR(10)='1.1' 
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(50)='test' 
DECLARE @treelevel INT 
DECLARE @OrgCompCode_Parent NVARCHAR(10)='1.1' 
DECLARE @OrgCompCode_Child NVARCHAR(10)='1.1.1' 
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(max) 

SELECT @treelevel = @@NESTLEVEL - 1 

SET @SQLQuery = 'insert into ' + @table_name 
                + 
' (level,OrgCompCode_Parent,OrgCompCode_Child) values (replicate(CHAR(45), ' 
                + Ltrim(Str(@treelevel)) 
                + ' * 1)          + ltrim(str(' 
                + Ltrim(Str(@treelevel)) + ')),''' + ( @OrgCompCode_Parent ) + 
                ''',''' + 
                                @OrgCompCode_Child + ')' 

EXEC (@SQLQuery) 

SELECT @SQLQuery
```

And below are the raised error. Hope someone could help me. Thanks.

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string '1.1.1)'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '1.1.1)'.
>   (1 row(s) affected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this by running a `Print`

```
DECLARE @p_orgcompreq NVARCHAR(10)='1.1' 
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(50)='test' 
DECLARE @treelevel INT 
DECLARE @OrgCompCode_Parent NVARCHAR(10)='1.1' 
DECLARE @OrgCompCode_Child NVARCHAR(10)='1.1.1' 
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(max) 

SELECT @treelevel = @@NESTLEVEL - 1 

SET @SQLQuery = 'insert into ' + @table_name 
                + 
' (level,OrgCompCode_Parent,OrgCompCode_Child) values (replicate(CHAR(45), ' 
                + Ltrim(Str(@treelevel)) 
                + ' * 1)          + ltrim(str(' 
                + Ltrim(Str(@treelevel)) + ')),''' + ( @OrgCompCode_Parent ) + 
                ''',''' + 
                                @OrgCompCode_Child + ')' 

Print @SQLQuery
```

This will show you the following message:

```
insert into test (level,OrgCompCode_Parent,OrgCompCode_Child) values (replicate(CHAR(45), -1 * 1)          + ltrim(str(-1)),'1.1','1.1.1)
```

**Edit**

Looking at the error this is the section where the error is `@OrgCompCode_Child + ')'` and as such the following should resolve this:

```
DECLARE @p_orgcompreq NVARCHAR(10)='1.1' 
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(50)='test' 
DECLARE @treelevel INT 
DECLARE @OrgCompCode_Parent NVARCHAR(10)='1.1' 
DECLARE @OrgCompCode_Child NVARCHAR(10)='1.1.1'''
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(max) 

SELECT @treelevel = @@NESTLEVEL - 1 

SET @SQLQuery = 'insert into ' + @table_name 
                + 
' (level,OrgCompCode_Parent,OrgCompCode_Child) values (replicate(CHAR(45), ' 
                + Ltrim(Str(@treelevel)) 
                + ' * 1)        + ltrim(str(' 
                + Ltrim(Str(@treelevel)) + ')),''' + ( @OrgCompCode_Parent ) + 
                ''',''' + 
                                @OrgCompCode_Child + ')'
```

**OR**

```
DECLARE @p_orgcompreq NVARCHAR(10)='1.1' 
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(50)='test' 
DECLARE @treelevel INT 
DECLARE @OrgCompCode_Parent NVARCHAR(10)='1.1' 
DECLARE @OrgCompCode_Child NVARCHAR(10)='1.1.1'
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(max) 

SELECT @treelevel = @@NESTLEVEL - 1 

SET @SQLQuery = 'insert into ' + @table_name 
                + 
' (level,OrgCompCode_Parent,OrgCompCode_Child) values (replicate(CHAR(45), ' 
                + Ltrim(Str(@treelevel)) 
                + ' * 1)        + ltrim(str(' 
                + Ltrim(Str(@treelevel)) + ')),''' + ( @OrgCompCode_Parent ) + 
                ''',''' + 
                                @OrgCompCode_Child +''''  + ')'

print @SQLQuery
EXEC (@SQLQuery) 

SELECT @SQLQuery
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @Tom : Thank you very much Tom, this is perfect.

Comment: @EliseoJr, No worries :)

Comment: @EliseoJr, If you are happy with this solution please could you mark this as the answer? Thank you :)

Comment: @Tom, how to mark this as answer? Sorry I do not know how to.

Comment: @EliseoJr, Next to my post you should see a tick? if you press this then it will be marked as the answer. It will also help people in the future with the same issue as they will now this solution worked :)

Comment: @Tom, it took me to google how to. I saw it in the left corner of your post in gray so it was hard for me to see. It is grayed check icon, and when I press it, it became green. Above  was up and down icon for voting. Correct me if I am wrong.